# Lightning component transaction context for SOQL queries

Tags: soql, lightning-web-components, governorlimits

Do Lightning Web Components operate in their own transaction when it comes to SOQL query limits? For example, if I have a Lightning Page with several LWCs, can I focus on each LWC as a single entity with it's own transaction limits or do I need to be aware of the number of SOQL calls from each LWC?

Also a more general question in regards to best practices. If I need to summarize data from both the entire set of instances of an object, and a subset(s) of the instances, is it better to do a single SOQL query and iterate over the instances to calculate the summary values? Or is it better to issue two (or more) separate SOQL queries? I realize the answer here is probably contextual, but I'm never come across any guidelines from Salesforce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When LWC initially came out, several operations queued at once would share governor limits. This changed in [Winter '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_predictable_apex_limits.htm). Each call to the server now gets the full governor limits, even when using the boxcar feature that groups calls together. See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/270843/2984) for more details.

As far as using one query or two? Use one query and post-process in JavaScript. The database is more efficient than Apex for aggregating data, but JavaScript will save you time on the server, and will ultimately be faster.

Comment: Worth also being aware of [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293025/boxcaring-is-removed-from-lwc-components)